# Issue with back button in fragment android

Tags: android, fragment

I have made in appliction using fragments.First there is a home sreeen in which there is a login button.when user clicks the login button a new fragment is opened which has username and password in it.I have put the loginfragment into backstack so that user can navigate to the home screen.If the user enters the correct credentials in the login frag,main fragments is opened.I have also put the mainfrag so i can navigate back and forth.But now what i want is that when the user is on home screen and if he pressed the back button the app should close but in my case it is going back to login fragment.

For eg
1] if user press login button from home screen

```
backstack contains "login"
```

2] now if user enters correct credentials and clicks ok, main frag is opened

```
backstack contains "main"
                   "login"
```

3] now in main frag i have 2 buttons say A and B,now if the user clicks on button A

```
 backstack contains "A"
                    "main"
                     "login"
```

Now what i want is that when user clicks on back button when he is on main frag, the app should finish ,but in my case it goes back to login frag because login is still present in the backstack

Comment: Have you tried your issue without adding your home fragment to backstack?

Comment: Sir in home fragments i have few buttons which opens another frags,so it was necessary to put to home frag to backstack

Comment: Can you just call getActivity().finish() from where you need to close everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT -**

**Solution 1:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();      
}
```

**NOTE:**

*I assume - Home class is your current home screen Class and Main class is your main starting point of the application.*

*Use Flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and call very First page from the Home page.*

**Solution 2:**

If you have only one activity that handles all the fragments then just call,

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getActivity().finish();      
    }
```

Comment: see sir i have updated my post please do have a look

Comment: @user3844417 - No problem, this solution will always work. Don't forget to clear the stack with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. This will clear your backstack. And `finish()` will close the app.

Comment: but sir where to use this intent code??? also i found some where that we can use popfrombackstack

Comment: @user3844417 - Use this code on back button click. `popfrombackstack` is to pop the one fragment from stack but to clear all and exit app you need the above code.

Comment: Every fragment is part of some activity. Likewise, Mainfrag is part of your some activity so if you call it in that activity then it will get called.

Comment: but sir i am using only one Activity to call all the fragments

Comment: @user3844417 - Check my update. You still can use the above code in a fragment back click.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this :

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.isTracking()
            && !event.isCanceled()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Say if it is what you want :)

Comment: see sir i have updated my post please do have a look

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks back button, first you have get the entry from the stack. If the entry is your main fragment kill the app.

> android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); 
>                   finish();

Answer (score 0):

While you have only login fragment visible(only login fragment at ***fragment stack***), if back button is clicked then you want the activity to be closed?

**Solution:** Add `login` fragment to ***fragment stack*** without adding it to ***backstack*** (without using `addToBackStack()` method.)

For instance:

Adding a fragment without adding it to backstack:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Adding a fragment wiht adding it to backstack:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

> Before you call commit(), however, you might want to call
>   addToBackStack(), in order to add the transaction to a back stack of
>   fragment transactions. This back stack is managed by the activity and
>   allows the user to return to the previous fragment state, by pressing
>   the Back button.

[Read more about fragments.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: The OP also wants the navigation back and forth on back button click for other fragments as well which requires to call `addToBackStack` on each and every fragment before commit. This solution will not provide this navigation.

Comment: If I'm not missing the point, adding "A" and "main" fragments(or others except "login") to backstack should work for OP.

Comment: If you added the few fragments to backstack (as oppose to login fragment) then on pressing back button on login fragment will not cause the app to exit because other fragments are still there in backstack.